# iOS Swift 5 Material Components button text shrink after button tap

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, mdc-components, material-components-ios

I have a material button. When I tap on it, the text label in the button shrinks and stays small, never reverting to the original size after it is released.
The cocoa pods I am using is pod 'MaterialComponents/Buttons', '~> 92.4.0'

Before Tap

[image: Before Tap]

After Tap

[image: After Tap]

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialButtons

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

private let testButton: MDCButton = {
    let button = MDCButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Test", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: button.titleLabel!.font.fontName, size: 22)
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping;
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.title = "The Page"
    self.view.addSubview(testButton)
    var testConstraintsArray: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    testConstraintsArray.append(testButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    self.view.centerXAnchor))
    testConstraintsArray.append(testButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    self.view.centerYAnchor))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(testConstraintsArray)
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of our developers found the solution. Pretty simple fix but since we couldn't find an answer to it anywhere I thought I'd share.

```
button.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 20)
```

should have been....

```
button.setTitleFont(UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 20), for: .normal)
```